# Can't login to meta

Tags: status-completed, meta, login

I'm trying to login to https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/ . Going to the login page on meta automatically logs me in, and redirects me to the meta homepage, where I am logged out again. I can repeat this ad nauseum.

Obviously this Q belongs on meta, but I can't ask it there as I can't login.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is related to the DNS issues discussed here:

[Is Homebrew.SE in Private Beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69749/is-homebrew-se-in-private-beta).

If meta is not yet working for you, it should be working later today. I will be removing this question shortly thereafter.

Answer (score 3):

A better place to have posted this would be http://meta.stackoverflow.com, which is the "meta" for all of the StackExchange sites.

Apparently, [there is a DNS problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69755/meta-keeps-logging-me-out-of-parent/69763#69763). It should get sorted in the next 24 hours.

Comment: noted (though personally I think that particular facet of SE site organisation is a bit bonkers, and in hindsight I probably would have asked my question at http://meta.stackexchange.com/ , believing meta.so to be for questions about the original site. Looking for information about 1 site on a second does not make for the most intuitive user experience.

Comment: I don't disagree.